# iam using provider and get_it package while running the app it shows this error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, get-it

Bad state: GetIt: Object/factory with type Dio is not registered inside GetIt.
(Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;
Did you forget to register it?)

i add dio inside the get_it service but it still shows the same error

```
`Future\<void\> setup() async {
// sl.registerSingleton(Dio(sl()));
sl.registerSingleton(() =\> Dio());
sl.registerLazySingleton(() =\> DioClient(AppConstants.apiBaseURL, sl(),
loggingInterseptor: sl(), sharedPreferences: sl()));
sl.registerLazySingleton\<LoggingInterseptor\>(() =\> LoggingInterseptor());
sl.registerLazySingleton(() =\> SharedPreferencesProvider());

// User:----------------------------------------------------------------------
sl.registerLazySingleton(() =\> AuthProvider(authRepoUser: sl()));
sl.registerFactory(() =\> AuthRepoUser(
dioClient: sl(),
));
}\`
```

Comment: please,fix the code you posted so we can read it better

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the type of the instance when you register it to get it:
example:

```
  sl.registerLazySingleton<RemoteDataSource>(
        () => RemoteDataSourceImpl(sl()));
```